# How to form a new list from specific elements from 2 different lists?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to form a new list from 2 different lists on a menuStrip
button click but it either doesn't put them in `newList` list or it
shows it as empty. `List1` is a list for the first data file from a `.txt.` file, `List2` is the same, `newList` is for forming a new list from specific parameters from 2 lists. Suggestions?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            
            List<Pieces> List1;
            List<Pieces> List2;
            List<Pieces> newList;
            Pieces piece;
    
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            } 
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                enterSecondFileToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }              
           
            private void accordingToUsersSpecificationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
                FormAUsersList(List1,newList);
                FormAUsersList(List2,newList);
                ///newList was null error that makes no sense
                ///object refrence not set to an instance of an object 
                ///error
                finalResults.Text += newList.ToString();
            }
           
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Close();
            }
            /// <summary>
            /// Form a list according to selected parameters by the user that we call
            /// 2 times to form a complete new list
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="list"></param>
            /// <param name="newList"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            private List<Pieces> FormAUsersList(List<Pieces> list, List<Pieces> newList)
            {          
                newList = new List<Pieces>();            
                int year = Convert.ToInt32(Years.SelectedItem); /// comboBox item that signifies years
                string type = Convert.ToString(Types.SelectedItem); /// comboBox item that signifies types
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (year <= list[i].PurchaseYear && type == list[i].Type)
                    {
                        newList.Add(list[i]);                                        
                    } 
                    
                }
               return newList;
            }
    }
```

Comment: There are several things wrong with this code. You hand it a newlist and create a newlist inside your routine. The returned list is not used anywhere so the second call also creates a newlist which in turn is not used either. You are confusing local and global lists with the samen name 'newlist'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I refactored your code. I had to remove your Form code because it doesn't compile locally of course:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Pieces
{
public class Piece
{
    public class Piece
    {
        public Piece(int purchaseYear, string type)
        {
            PurchaseYear = purchaseYear;
            Type = type;
        }
        public int PurchaseYear { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        // EDIT:
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Purchased year: {PurchaseYear} Type: {Type}";
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1
    {
        List<Piece> List1 = new List<Piece> { new Piece (2022, "????"), new Piece(2021, "????") };
        List<Piece> List2 = new List<Piece> { new Piece(2020, "????"), new Piece(2019, "????") };
        List<Piece> newList;

        public Form1()
        {
            accordingToUsersSpecificationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(null, null); // Just so it compiles.
        }

        private void accordingToUsersSpecificationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var year = 2018;
            var type = "????";

            // Create the list outside your FormUsersList() method, No need to pass newlist to it.
            newList = new List<Piece>();
            FormAUsersList(List1);
            FormAUsersList(List2);

            // Now the same with LINQ
            newList = new List<Piece>();
            FormAUsersListWithLinq(List1, year, type);
            FormAUsersListWithLinq(List2, year, type);

            // Or just LINQ
            newList = List1
                      .Union(List2)
                      .Where(x => x.PurchaseYear >= year && x.Type == type)
                      .ToList();

            // EDIT:
            newList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Form a list according to selected parameters by the user that we call
        /// 2 times to form a complete new list
        /// </summary>
        private void FormAUsersList(List<Piece> list)
        {
            int year = 2018; // Just so it compiles
            string type = "????"; // Just so it compiles
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (year <= list[i].PurchaseYear && type == list[i].Type)
                {
                    newList.Add(list[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void FormAUsersListWithLinq(List<Piece> list, int year, string type)
        {
            newList.AddRange(list.Where(x => x.PurchaseYear >= year && x.Type == type));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Second question, where should I look for my mistake if it still shows this "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[laboras02_08_P2.Pieces]", while trying to print it like this - "finalResults.Text += newList.ToString();". "Pieces" is my data class, while debugging I can see that it catches and tries to put what I want to into the newList, but fails?

Comment: The .ToString() when not overriden prints out the name of the type.

Comment: @Arnas I put in 2 EDIT's for you

Comment: @Arnas If the answer can solve your problem, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. If not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug. each time you create a new list but don't return it back.

You should remove newList = new List();  outside

```
private List<Pieces> FormAUsersList(List<Pieces> list, List<Pieces> newList)
 {          
     newList = new List<Pieces>();  //  remove from here
       .....
}
```

and code should be

```
 newList = new List<Pieces>();
FormAUsersList(List1,newList);
 FormAUsersList(List2,newList);
```

and IMHO you can use linq as well

```
var itemsToAdd=list.Where(i=> year <= i.PurchaseYear && type == i.Type);

if(itemsToAdd!=null) newList.AddRange(itemsToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have one call to FormAUsersList that passes in List1 and List2, like so:

```
FormAUsersList(List1,List2);
```

In your code, the FormAUsersList method receives newList and immediately replaces it with a new, empty List, which doesn't make sense. The FormAUsersList should instead look more like:

```
private List<Pieces> FormAUsersList(List<Pieces> list1, List<Pieces> list2)
{
    List<Pieces> newList = new List<Pieces>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        newList.Add(list1.ElementAt(i).PurchaseYear, list2.ElementAt(i).Whatever);
    }

    return newList;
}
```

Note that this code assumes list1 and list2 are the same length.